# trying to adjust regex to remove new lines

Tags: php, regex

Hi I am looking to adjust this regex:

```
/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\]\r\n/is
```

To basically ignore the new lines (basically I want my quote system to remove any new lines after the quote bbcode to stop there being a double space after the quoting.

Currently i'm just doing this as the replace:

```
$replace = "<div class=\"quote\"><span class=\"strong\">Quote</span><br />$1</div>";
```

So it directly removes the new line, but it breaks say if the quote code is the last thing on the page and no new line after it.

Comment: When HTML is rendered line breaks [`\r\n`] are ignored. You probably have some margin or padding at the bottom of `div.quote` or at the top of whatever element follows it.

Comment: \r\n is changed to <br /> by my code, which is why i want them removed if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a simple way:

```
$body = str_replace("[/quote]\r\n", '[/quote]', $body);
```

Just remove them before it's checked in the text. Simple solution and no fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Add a non-capturing group at the end, like so:

```
/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\](?:\r\n)*/is
```

Or a simple character class:

```
/\[quote\](.+?)\[\/quote\][\r\n]*/is
```

Which will catch lone `\n` breaks as well.